# How can I let the user save model data from backbone js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

Ok, so I have a reasonably functional backbone.js app. Within the app I have various models, views and collections. At a point when I am showing a collection as a table on the screen, I want to give the user a link to click that will save the data, that is already present in the collection, to their downloads folder as a CSV! I really can't work out how to do this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

On another page I am displaying a collection as a paginated list, only downloading the next page of data when the user gets to the end. I would also like a download link for this collection but I can't work out how to do it with backbone. I think I want to do a model fetch that somehow lets the user save it rather than populating the model..? Perhaps there is a better way?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the app is organized, having a view with an event firing a function makes sense to me.

On the firing of that event, put `collection.toJSON` into a template for the CSV, create a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) with it, then use a library (like [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)) to shim out `saveAs` and offer the ability to download.

So something like a view with these pieces involved:

```
events: {
  'click .download': 'downloadCollection'
},

downloadCollection: function() {
  var collectionCSV = csvTemplate(this.collection.toJSON());
  var blob = new Blob([collectionCSV], {type: 'text/csv'});
  saveAs(blob, 'list.csv'); //html5 saveAs implemented by FileSaver
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was having real trouble finding a simple cross browser way to do this. Presumably FileSaver handles most browsers?